# How do you make a Node class field member if the Node class is in a separate file?

Tags: java, linked-list, class-members

This is a total noob question since I cannot remember.

I want to make a homemade version of linked lists and my LinkedList class is as follows:

```
package stacks;

import java.io.*;

class Node<T>
{
    T data;
    Node<T> next;

    Node(T data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class LinkedList<AnyType>
{
    private Node<AnyType> head, tail;
}
```

I want to move the Node class to its own file in the same directory as the Linked List class. How to I reference the Node class as a field in the Linked List class if I do this?

Node class:

```
package stacks;

public class Node<T>
{
    T data;
    Node<T> next;

    Node(T data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Linked List class:

```
package stacks;

import java.io.*;

public class LinkedList<AnyType>
{
    private Node<AnyType> head, tail;
}
```

This doesn't work if the node class is in a separate file. Since the "Node" is a field member of the LinkedList class, I do not want to instantiate it yet. I just want a reference to the class.

This is a very basic question, I know. I haven't done object oriented programming in a while so I don't really remember these basic things.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
LinkedList.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    private Node<AnyType> head, tail;
            ^
  symbol:   class Node
  location: class LinkedList<AnyType>
  where AnyType is a type-variable:
    AnyType extends Object declared in class LinkedList
1 error
```

Comment: *"This doesn't work if the node class is in a separate file"* -- please be more specific and provide more detail since "doesn't work" doesn't tell us what problems you in fact are having. Doesn't work, how? What errors are you seeing? Please show two small complete separate classes and the full error messages you are seeing, if any.

Comment: If both files are in the same package, then there is no need to do an import. If they are in separate packages, then you will need to import the Node class into your LinkedList class.

Comment: And please tell how you are compiling and running your classes. Are you using an IDE or are you running from the command line?

Comment: Make sure that you've fully compiled the Node class. Also, please check out the [What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25706216/) question and answers.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I just updated my question. They are in the same package called stacks.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am compiling as : javac LinkedList.java java LinkedList

Comment: Are you compiling the Node.java class?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels no... that's what it was.

Comment: e.g., `javac Node.java LinkedList.java`

Comment: Use a decent IDE or learn to use Maven.

Comment: But glad that your problem has been solved.